# Use Transient property in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

First off, I'm new to Hibernate.
I have a standalone Java application built in Netbeans, trying to keep to the MVC model as much as possible. My model classes resemble the database tables and columns as much as possible. The database is normalized to avoid redundancy.
However, I noticed that it was convenient to have a certain property available in many of my model classes. This property is available in the database, but in most situations it is necessary to do multiple joins to get it.
Therefore, I added this property to my model classes for easier access.

Example:
`Object A` has a relation with `Object B`, which has a relation with `Object C`. `Object C` has the `property X`.
The relations are one-to-many; `Object A` has the primary key of `Object B` as a column, and so forth.
Now I want to find all `Object A` connected to `property X`. I have to do multiple joins to get the answer. `Property X` also applies to `Object A`, but I don't want it as a property for `Object A` in the database, as that is redundancy. In the application, I add this `property X` to the class of `Object A`for convenient access.

Now I want to implement Hibernate instead of my own designed (service) classes, and I'm not sure what to do with this property. I have defined it as 'Transient' in the POJO, but how do I fill this property? If I let Hibernate perform a get tot the database and return the object (`Object A`) to me, it will not have this property. Do I need to have an extra constructor with this property and transform Hibernate's object to the one containing this property and return that to the original method that asked for it?

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Hibernate you probably have something like this in your class A:

```
@OneToMany
private Collection<B> listOfB;
```

In B you will have:

```
@OneToMany
private Collection<C> listOfC;
```

So when you get the A Entity from your Database you can get x doing:

```
a.getlistOfB(0).getListOfC(0).getX();
```

Comment: It's a Set, but same idea. Thanks :)